# how to get path of file in raw folder android

Tags: java, android, path

I need the String Address of the *raw* folder directory
this is my code but it ends with crash

```
private String zipPath = String.valueOf(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.zipfile));
```

Answer (score 2):

Resources are files on your development machine. They are not files on the device. There is no path to your raw resource.

`getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.zipfile)` is fine, to give you an `InputStream`. Use that to read in your resource contents.

And, in general, calling `String.valueOf()` or `toString()` on objects is for getting some developer-readable string. The string representation of an `InputStream` is not going to be a filesystem path.